# Windows Storage Server Disk Name

Tags: windows-storage-server

My windows storage server event log reports "Disk 2" for an IO operation being retried. The disks all show healthy when inspected. Using windows explorer or doing transfers cripples/hangs.  So i suspect Disk 2 is the culprit.

Being remote i want to deactivate Disk 2 and turn on the hot spare. However deactivating the disks seems to be by friendly names. How can i decode the friendly names to actual disks in the event log? i tried "Get-PhysicalDisk"

Thanks in advance - i have little experience in Storage Server.

### FriendlyName

PhysicalDisk5
PhysicalDisk0
PhysicalDisk1
PhysicalDisk2
PhysicalDisk2
PhysicalDisk4
PhysicalDisk6
PhysicalDisk7

Answer (score 0):

This describes the `Get-PhysicalDisk` cmdlet:  [Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848686(v=wps.630).aspx).  Near the bottom it describes what the cmdlet returns, which is a MSFT_PhysicalDisk object...  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh830532.aspx) lists the members of that object class, one of which is FriendlyName.

So, look for a `-Properties` parameter, and if it is there, specify `FriendlyName`.  Use `Get-Member` to see what properties are actually on objects returned.  Often, what is displayed is a subset of what's returned by default, which is a subset of the complete set of parameters for the object.

I don't have Storage Server module available to test this.  But I can give an example from ActiveDirectory.  There are many members on user objects, and the set is extensible, for instance when you add Exchange it adds a ton of members to the user object.  One commonly used member is the `userPrincipalName` property.  But it's not returned by default when you use `Get-ADUser username`.  You have to use `Get-ADUser username -Property userPrincipalName`to require it.

Comment: Thanks. When i try "Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk0" it echos the Friendly name. " Get-Disk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk0" says no No MSFT_Disk objects found with property 'FriendlyName' equal to 'PhysicalDisk0'.

Comment: Use `Get-PhysicalDisk * | Get-Member` to get a list of properties available.  Then `Get-PhysicalDisk * | Select-Object -Property <property1>,<property2>,<etc>`.  In the first command, using an actual Physical Disk ID works more efficiently, but if you don't know one, use the *.  So the first command gets you a list of properties.  The second one gets those properties for all disks.  Depending on the cmdlet, and what the required and implied parameters are, you may need to use -Filter * to get all the disks, instead of just *.